# GoogleCloudMessaging Android Import Issue

Tags: android, import, google-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to implement push notifications in an Android application, and I found plenty of examples, but they all import `com.google.android.gcm` - a package that has since been deprecated with (supposedly) its features folded into the `GooglePlayServices` package (I have **version 15**). I've tried to hook up that as well, and it does not work with the example code, and seems to require the deprecated package.

Does anyone have any up to date examples?

Any help would be greatly appreciated in figuring this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why you are looking for other example while google have provided you complete working code example including both server and client. What do you need is just to check out source code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/checkout). Import project named "`gcm-client`" into work space. Add "`google-play-services_lib`" project from android sdk folder as a library. Change your SENDER_ID in DemoActivity located in `com.google.android.gcm.demo.app` package. That's it.

Please **ignore** samples/gcm-demo-client in same downloaded code directory. It uses old deprecated classes. You may reuse its utility class `ServerUtilities` to send/delete registration id to/from your server. [Thanks  NickT for identifying ]

**Edit:**

Deprecated code is still exist as `gcm-client-deprecated` on given repository. Just ignore it and use `gcm-client`.

Comment: I do apologize, I must have downloaded an old version of that... because I opened it and it displayed the legacy code... my mistake, thanks for the help!

Comment: These are useful links. I should point out however, that samples/gcm-demo-client does in fact refer to the deprecated GCM classes. The gcm-client in itself does use the new method.

Comment: Ah that must have been what i opened when i downloaded it, not the gcm-client

Comment: Thanks NickT for helpful findings.

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for posting the original link. I only knew this code from web pages on  developer.android.com. In my opinion Google have made an unholy mess of the documentation for GCM and were most unprofessional in introducing GCM and then deprecating the original classes so quickly.