# alternate of google cloud messaging with example

Tags: android

Am using php/mysql server.I want to send messages from server whenever there is an update/new entry.I heard that google cloud messaging has been deprecated.How can i do this?can u provide example for the same

Answer (score 0):

**GCM for Android** is deprecated not the **GCM Service** itself. GCM is now integrated with the ***Google Play Services***

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Android Cloud to Device Messaging (**C2DM**) is deprecated,not **GCM**(google cloud messaging).i.e. You may use GCM which is next Generation of C2DM.

Note :- Initially GCM used its own jar (**gcm-client**) which has  been deprecated,and now it integrated with the **Google Play Services**

For more info see [Document](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html).

And this answer will help you [GoogleCloudMessaging Android Import Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169053/googlecloudmessaging-android-import-issue)